# How to transfer Launchpad SSH and OpenPGP keys to another computer?

Tags: ssh, launchpad, gnupg, seahorse

I maintain some PPAs at launchpad. I created SSH and OpenPGP keys for that.

If I need to update a PPA from another computer, I will have to transfer these keys there.

I tried to export and import them using Seahorse (*Keys & Passwords*), but they did not want to import.

What is the easiest way to transfer keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seahorse' *Export* function only exports public keys, not private ones.

You can easily export the private key from the command line using `gpg --export-secret-keys [key-id] > secret.pgp`.

An alternative would be to migrate the whole `~/.gnupg` folder to the new machine (you might have to fix some permission issues afterwards, mostly making sure you and only you can read and write from/to that folder).

Private SSH keys are usually stored in `~/.ssh`, I'd also simply just copy the whole folder to the new machine.

Comment: I will try that. And what about ssh?

Comment: Just realized that was missing, too -- already added it right before reading your comment.

Comment: Just copied directories and it worked. Seahorse found them too.